# Filter outgoing connections but allow incoming

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I a computer on my local network that I want to have accessible from any computer on the local network as well as from the internet, but I don't want it to be able to connect to other computers. I plan on giving access to this computer to an "untrusted" party, but I don't want them meandering all over my local network. Is this possible? I need windows solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would:

1. Get a router/switch infrastructure that supports VLANs and routing
2. Tag the computer off to its own broadcast domain -- i.e. set the switch port to tag all incoming traffic
3. Set your LAN up as VLAN 0 -- i.e. untagged
4. Set the untrusted computer up on its own network - for ex 192.168.1.0/24
5. Your LAN should be its own existing network - 192.168.0.0/24
6. Set the router up to NAT traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.0.0/24 out to the Internet
7. Set the router up to allow packets creating connections from 192.168.0.0/24 (private LAN) into 192.168.1.0/24 (untrusted LAN) but not vice versa.